# Passing image between two pages

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7

I just pass the image between two pages, by passing the `byte[]` and I try to convert the `byte[]` to image in page 2 using the following code,

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (e.Uri.OriginalString.Contains("img"))
    {
        expenseDetails = AuthOrgClass.expenseDetails;
        imgData = NavigationService.GetImageNavigationData();
        fill();   
    }
}

private void fill()
{
   var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
   var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imgData);
   bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);
   ImageBox.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

While executing the line `bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);`
I get the exception

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

What could be the problem?

Comment: what does NavigationService.GetImageNavigationData() look like? Are you sure imgData is not null?

Comment: Add a `try catch` around `bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);` the inside `fill()` method to get more detail on the exception and update your post.

Comment: Is GetImageNavigationData() a library function or your custom class library function? Cannot find that method in NavigationService.

Answer (score 1):

You should use IsolatedStorageSettings to store image as byte array. IsolatedStorageSettings  accessible in all application. So you can easily pass your byte array between any pages in application. try this may this will help you.

```
 SaveImageAsByteArray()
    {
    IsolatedStorageSettings MemorySettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (MemorySettings.Contains("ImageData"))
     MemorySettings["ImageData"] = your byte array;
    else
    MemorySettings.add("ImageData", your byte array;);

    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }



    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (e.Uri.OriginalString.Contains("img"))
        {

            fill();   
        }
    }

    private void fill()
    {
    IsolatedStorageSettings MemorySettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
     if (MemorySettings.Contains("ImageData"))
     byte[] bytes = MemorySettings["ImageData"] 
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
     BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
     image.SetSource(stream);
       ImageBox.Source = image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best Practice is take a global Image varible in App.xaml.cs,assign it at first page and take value from it at second page.It would never create a problem..:)